# Typescript: How can I ensure all keys in an object type are in a declared enum?

Tags: typescript

I had an object type declared using keys from an enum all set as strings:

```
enum MyProperties {
  PROP_A = 'propA',
  PROP_B = 'propB',
  PROP_C = 'propC'
}

type Foo {
  [value in MyProperties]: string;
}
```

How can I declare one of the properties in `Foo` as a number while still ensuring all of its keys are in `MyProperties`?

i.e.

```
type Foo {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
  propC: number;
}
```

Comment: You can use an utility type: Record<MyProperties, string | number>.

`type Foo = Record<MyProperties, string | number>;`

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for because I want to enforce `string` for `propA` and `propB`, `number` for `propC`.

Answer (score 1):

As easy as that

```
export type = Foo {
  [value in keyof typeof MyProperties]: string;
}
```

Comment: That won't work because I want one of the properties to be a number, the rest strings. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the initial question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question in a description, its not particularly clear what exactly you want

Comment: so then replace `string` with `string | number`

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for because I want to enforce `string` for `propA` and `propB`, `number` for `propC`. For example, I don't want to allow `propA` to be a `number`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific property to be typed as a number then you can do:

```
type Foo<T extends MyProperties> = {
  [value in MyProperties]: T extends value ? number : string;
}
```

Or you can use more generic solution:

```
enum MyProperties {
  PROP_A = 'propA',
  PROP_B = 'propB',
  PROP_C = 'propC'
}

type OneOf<T extends {
    [key: string]: any;
}, R, P extends keyof T = keyof T> = P extends keyof T ? {
   [K in P]: R;
} & {
    [K in keyof Omit<T, P>]: T[K];
} : never

type Foo = OneOf<{
  [value in MyProperties]: string;
}, number>

const k: Foo = {
   propA: "",
   propB: 3,
   propC: "",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decided to just go with:

```
enum MyProperties {
  PROP_A = 'propA',
  PROP_B = 'propB',
  PROP_C = 'propC'
}

type Foo {
  [MyProperties.PROP_A]: string;
  [MyProperties.PROP_B]: string;
  [MyProperties.PROP_C]: number;
}
```

Was hoping to find a slicker yet simple way to do this. With such a small set of properties, though, just being explicit seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a type for an object which has keys matching every value in an enum and values that are different (`string` and `number` in your example).  You want to enforce that every key matches the appropriate value, while also requiring that all keys have some value.

This can be a bit confusing since we are trying to enforce typings on a **type** rather than an object.  But there are a few things we can do.

1. We can separate the properties into groups by value type. Since we only have two value types here, we can define one as the leftovers from the other.

```
type NumberProperties = MyProperties.PROP_C;

type StringProperties = Exclude<MyProperties, NumberProperties>

type Foo = {
    [K in NumberProperties]: number;
} & {
    [K in StringProperties]: string;
}
```

[Link](https://tsplay.dev/KN7G4N)

2. We can use a helper type `MissingKeys` to check at compile time that we haven't forgotten anything.  We do need to check it ourselves, as no error is thrown.

```
enum MyProperties {
  PROP_A = 'propA',
  PROP_B = 'propB',
  PROP_C = 'propC'
}

type Foo = {
  [MyProperties.PROP_B]: string;
  [MyProperties.PROP_C]: number;
}

type MissingKeys = Exclude<MyProperties, keyof Foo> // evaluates to MyProperties.PROP_A
```

[Link](https://tsplay.dev/rNdJ6W)

3. **My Favorite**. We can add an declaration to our type that states that any missing properties must be set in objects implementing `Foo`.  Let's give it an illogical value so that we can notice that something is missing from `Foo` and adjust `Foo` accordingly.  I like this one because we get a big red underline so it's obvious that the type is wrong.

```
type DefinedFoo = {
  [MyProperties.PROP_B]: string;
  [MyProperties.PROP_C]: number;
}

type MissingKeys = Exclude<MyProperties, keyof DefinedFoo> // evaluates to MyProperties.PROP_A

type Foo = DefinedFoo & {
    [K in MissingKeys]-?: "missing property definition" 
}

const fooImplementation1: Foo = {
    [MyProperties.PROP_B]: "b",
    [MyProperties.PROP_C]: 0,
}
// gives an error: Property 'propA' is missing...

const fooImplementation2: Foo = {
    [MyProperties.PROP_A]: "a",
    [MyProperties.PROP_B]: "b",
    [MyProperties.PROP_C]: 0,
}
// gives an error: Type of computed property's value is '"a"', which is not assignable to type '"missing property definition"'
```

[Link](https://tsplay.dev/GmZB9m)